# Spring Batch ResultSet got closed by other before all data being fetched

Tags: db2, spring-batch

I am trying to setup the DB2 source as the persistence for the Batch meta data.  I am getting this stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED, VERSION, JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION from rhall.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION where JOB_INSTANCE_ID = ? order by JOB_EXECUTION_ID desc]; SQL state [null]; error code [-4470]; [jcc][t4][10120][10898][3.57.82] Invalid operation: result set is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][10120][10898][3.57.82] Invalid operation: result set is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null
   at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
   at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
   at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
   at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:645)
   at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:680)
   at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:712)
   at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:722)
   at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:777)
   at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.findJobExecutions(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:131)
   at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getStepExecutionCount(SimpleJobRepository.java:253)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
   at $Proxy32.getStepExecutionCount(Unknown Source)
   at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.isStepRestart(JobFlowExecutor.java:82)
   at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:63)
   at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
   at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) ... 22 more
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][10120][10898][3.57.82] Invalid operation: result set is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null
   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:660)
   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:60)
   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:103)
   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zl.Db(zl.java:4219)
   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zl.q(zl.java:4180)
   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zl.c(zl.java:1009)
   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zl.getTimestamp(zl.java:985)
   at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcResultSet.getTimestamp(WSJdbcResultSet.java:2607)
   at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao$JobExecutionRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:425)
   at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao$JobExecutionRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:396)
   at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93)
   at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
   at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:693)
   at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:629) 
  ... 45 more
```

I trace the code, and found the problem around this method: `JdbcJobExecutionDao.mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)`

(I am  using Spring-batch version 3.0.6)  List paste the method here for your
 convenience,

```
public JobExecution mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
 throws SQLException {          
 Long id = rs.getLong(1);           
 String jobConfigurationLocation = rs.getString(10);            
 JobExecution jobExecution;             
 if (jobParameters == null) {
    jobParameters = getJobParameters(id);           
 }
 if (jobInstance == null) {
    jobExecution = new JobExecution(id, jobParameters, jobConfigurationLocation);           
 } else {
    jobExecution = new JobExecution(jobInstance, id, jobParameters, jobConfigurationLocation);          
 }
 jobExecution.setStartTime(rs.getTimestamp(2));
 jobExecution.setEndTime(rs.getTimestamp(3));
 jobExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.valueOf(rs.getString(4)));
 jobExecution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus(rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6)));             
 jobExecution.setCreateTime(rs.getTimestamp(7));
 jobExecution.setLastUpdated(rs.getTimestamp(8));
 jobExecution.setVersion(rs.getInt(9));          
 return jobExecution;        
}
```

As I trace it, I notice that the problem is in the `getJobParameters(id)` method.  This method performs another query to the `JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS` table for paramaters for the given job id.  But within this method, the `getConnection` method returns the same connection as in the current context.  After the query, the finally block closes the `resultSet`.  So when the control gets back to the `mapRow` method, it failed at this line:

```
jobExecution.setStartTime(rs.getTimestamp(2));
```

It is because the `rs` has already been closed by the `getJobParameters(id)` method.

Wondering if I did wrong?  Please point me out.
Many thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue and started a bounty...

SQL state [55032]; error code [-1224]; [jcc][t4][2055][14191][4.19.26] The database manager is not able to accept new requests, has terminated all requests in progress,
or has terminated this particular request due to unexpected error conditions detected at the target system. ERRORCODE=-1224, SQLSTATE=55032

Comment: do you have some code in your job (service or DAO) marked with @Transactional?

Answer (score 2):

removing `@Transactional` from my method that uses the Batch Infrastructure classes, ie, `JobExplorer`, solves this issues around the closed `ResultSet`.